# Statistics and computing journal bibliography style

Tags: bibliographystyle, sv-classes

I am sending our manuscript to Statistics and Computing Journal, however, its bibliography style isn't found in any `svjour` style! The style is as follows:

Hamburger, C.: Quasimonotonicity, regularity and duality for nonlinear systems of partial differential equations. Ann. Mat. Pura Appl. 169, 321–354 (1995)

Any suggestion  how to build this style on `\documentclass[twocolumn]{svjour3}`? Many thanks in advance!

Comment: If you are sending it to the journal, ask the editor(s).

Comment: Actually, I did! If I give back a useful answer, I will share it here! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

For those who can not find the journal's references style: The following code

```tex
\begin{thebibliography}{9}
\bibitem[Brijs et al.(2004)]{Brijs}
Brijs, T.,  Karlis, D., Swinnen, D.,   Vanhoof, K.,  Wets, G., Manchanda, P.: A multivariate Poisson mixture model for marketing applications. Statistica Neerlandica. \textbf{58}(3),  322-348 (2004)  
\end{thebibliography}
```

gives the following [image]